# google mobile ad banner ad view not showing in ios 9.3.2

Tags: mobile, banner

I have integrated Google Mobile Ad based on the gitHub Banner sample and got it working for devices with iOS < 9.0. But got into problem with devices running 9.3.2 iOS.

So to in trying to isolate where possible and error can occur, I downloaded the github sample code for banner ad. To get the sample running I remove any code related to firebase and added the Google Mobile Ads framework version 7.8.1. The banner ads showed the test ad that comes with the sample code.

Then I modify the adUnitId to use what I have been using from my app. And the sample code duplicated the behavior I've seen with my app. The banner ad only got displayed for devices running below 9.0 iOS. Since only 9.0+ iOS devices I have are all running version 9.3.2, and none of these devices can display the banner ad. But I can get test ads to display oh 9.3.2 devices when I use the via google's test adUnitId or by setting the testDevice of the ad request.

To debug what may be different between devices running iOS <9.0 and 9.3.2 when I use my adUnitId, I added the GADBannerViewDelegate and breakpoint on adViewDidReceiveAd method of the delegate. And devices running 9.3.2 show this method did get called. Ads do show being initialized. And I found the url pointing to a seem like a valid doubleclick.net ad path. But still nothing get displayed when the process is continued.

Oh, forgot to mention this earlier. I did confirmed that the ATS is disabled from the Info.plist in both the sample code and my app.

I have run out of ideas on what may have gone wrong and how to proceed. Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue lies in the ad key used. When I created a new banner unit ad key, everything works just like the google sample key.